# Impossible to delete attached file in SAP CRM email form

Tags: abap, sap-crm

that there’s a missing object in the process which cause the system to raise an exemption. Can also check CRM mail form configuration with regards to attachments. Something in the configuration might be causing the object to be null.

**Issue:**

Attachments were not able to delete from mail form

> ZCRMXX_MF_CAP

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Connect to **WEB UI** with roles **ZMASTERDATA** role.
2. Select "Service" in left menu and click on "Mail forms" field.
3. Click on "Search" button and select mail form ID "TEST" .
4. In top menu, click on "More" and select "Attach file".
5. Select File attached and try to delete it.

Comment: <sarcasm> Please provide logon and system details so we can look into your problem. </sarcasm> Note that all the objects you mention start with a Z, i.e. these are custom objects unique to your system. If you provide the logic that is used to delete these attachments what standard SAP transactions are used we might be able to help you.

Comment: @GertBeukema thanks a lot your reply actually error is coming in standard code and issue is this when we have more then 1 attachment its working perfectly but when we have only 1 attachment it give exception.                                                                                             line 30 causes the dump due to null object lr_iterator.  Object lr_iterator supposed to have a value but it shows below that its INITIAL